# Monaco Editor (Diff Viewer) - How do I only show the changes in a diff without the rest of the file contents

Tags: reactjs, diff, monaco-editor

It doesn't seem like there's an obvious way to do this, and wondered if I was missing something. I have an editor setup as a diff viewer, displaying fairly large JSON configuration files and I want, in the side-by-side view, to only show the changes (additions and removals) without the rest of the file contents to scroll through.

I can't even find an example of anyone trying to hack this. Is it possible?

I do not have any approaches to try, and after looking at the diff contents in the DOM, it's not really even clear how I'd hack a solution. Help! :)